# Do I need ground for RS-485 if it is galvanically isolated?

Tags: ground, grounding, rs485

I am designing an RS-485 communication.

The communication interface is isolated. So, only the noninverting and inverting line will be connected outside to the cable.

I know that I have to include the signal ground for the RS-485 interface to be perfect. However, I am short on the number of terminals I can use.

Will it be OK if the interface is isolated and the noninverting and inverting line is pulled up and down with 47k Ohm resistor?

Will 47K Ohm pull-down resistor some how work level the ground level of the system to same level of the network even if the signal ground is not connected?

Comment: RS-485 is not a current loop. You must connect the "grounds" of the transceivers together - note this is the 'isolated' ground on each side.

Comment: Steve, would you mind sharing the transceiver with the scheme how you are connecting RS485 lines. since Galvanic isolation means, everything should be isolated Power, GND and RS485 lines.

Comment: @AKR The power is isolated through transformer from main power. the TX, RX, and DE lines from MCU are isolated through digital isolator (from Silicon Labs). Then the other side of digital isolator is connected to RS485 Transceiver.

Comment: @Steve When you say Power, shall I assume its both both Power line and GND line.?

Comment: Common-mode voltage will bite you without a ground connection. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/232975/rs485-network-ground-pin-when-to-connect/232987
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128618/ground-connection-in-differential-signals/137371

Comment: @AKr Yes. you can assume that. Good point.

Comment: @brhans Why it could still bite you even though everything is isolated?

Comment: @Unknown123 - inductive & capacitive coupling, static pick, etc can induce voltages in isolated systems. If you don't connect your isolated grounds together across your RS485 link you have no idea what the voltage difference is between them and can easily exceed the allowable common-mode voltage of your RS485 tranceivers' data lines.

Comment: @brhans I don't see such practice on [ADM2485](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM2485.pdf) datasheet, are you sure?

Comment: @Unknown123 - that datasheet doesn't show any examples of 2 or more RS485 drivers connected together, so it's not surprising that you don't see what I'm describing there. Try Analog's [AN-960](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-960.pdf) or Maxim's [Tutorial 763](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/7/763.html) and [others](https://www.ccontrols.com/pdf/ExtV1N1.pdf), [Fig.10 in this TI App Note](http://www.grantronics.com.au/docs/TIA-EIA-485.pdf).

Comment: ... and just so we're clear - I'm not talking about connecting GND1 and GND2 on your ADM2485.

Comment: @brhans It's the ground between transceivers that you're talking about. I misunderstood, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work. Perhaps 47 kΩ is little too high (it's a very big resistance). It depends on how many nodes you will connect. 47 kΩ is OK for each node, but then you can put additional lower resistance at the both ends.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkSjdl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Vcc and GND are floating power rails of each independent power source, the shield of the cable is connected to the earth. GNDs of nodes are not connected together as well the Vcc.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what "earth" the shield of the cable connects to?

Comment: @jonathanjo He is refering to the earth connection on the main power line, i.o. the physical earth. This earth connection protects the communication network from interference and transient power surges. It should not be connected with GND or COM.

Comment: Vcc and GND on the node modules can be independent but there should be a common ground on the transmission line, else there will be huge parasite signals. It may work under good conditions but not very well.  AFAIK, only one 47K resistor is needed. But the value of the pull up and pull down resistors should decrease as the number of nodes increases. Termination resistors are needed on long cables (dozen of feet or meters).

Comment: @Fredled many thanks for your comments but I'm afraid I'm still a little confused in the case of multidrop RS-485 across different buildings with no "main power line"; each has its own power (mix of diff phases, local gen, solar, battery).  Do we connect together all the isolated grounds of the RS-485 transceivers?  Or do you mean a stake into the soil? Concretely I'm talking about `GND2` of eg [ADM 2763E](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm2761e_adm2763e.pdf)

Comment: @jonathanjo All RS-485 transceivers must share a common reference. Which means, for all transceivers, their grounds must be tied together for the bus to work. For isolated receivers, it means the bus side ground. If you have a question about it, ask a new one, but I think what you want to know has been a popular question.

Comment: @justme thanks -- what you say is what I thought was the case.  But it seems to contradict this answer, where marko says "GNDs of nodes are not connected together".

Comment: @jonathanjo You don't need a main power line to connect to earth. I mentioned main to make sure you don't mix it with GND. Yes it's the metal rod in the soil near the building and the wire connected to it. This wire can run separately from power line wires. but they show up often together. It's at the same time a shield for the RS485 signal and a protection for humans.